# Android Room library with Kotlin Flow toList() doesn't work

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I made a simple example app with using Room and Flows:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val build = Room.databaseBuilder(this, FinanceDatabase::class.java, "database.db")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
    GlobalScope.launch {
        build.currencyDao().addCurrency(CurrencyLocalEntity(1))
        val toList = build.currencyDao().getAllCurrencies().toList()
        Log.d("test", "list - $toList")
    }
}
}

@Entity(tableName = "currency")
data class CurrencyLocalEntity(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "currencyId")
        var id: Int
) {
    constructor() : this(-1)
}

@Dao
interface CurrencyDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM currency")
fun getAllCurrencies(): Flow<CurrencyLocalEntity>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun addCurrency(currency: CurrencyLocalEntity)
}

@Database(entities = [CurrencyLocalEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class FinanceDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun currencyDao(): CurrencyDao
}
```

I want to use `toList()` function as in code above but something gets wrong and even Log doesn't print. At the same time using `collect()` works fine and gives me all records.

Can anybody explain to me what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The [examples in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-flow) suggest that when you want to return a `Flow` from a query that produces multiple items, `Flow<List<T>>` should be used.  The example that returns `Flow<T>` is for a query that returns a single item. Your `getAllCurrencies()` is expecting Room to emit for each item in the `currency` table.  I don't think it supports that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong here but I'll address the main issue.

`Flow`s returned by room emit the result of the query everytime the database is modified. (This might be scoped to table changes instead of the whole database).

Since the database can change at any point in the future, the `Flow` will (more or less) never complete because a change can always happen.

Your calling `toList()` on the returned `Flow` will suspend forever, since the `Flow` never completes. This conceptually makes sense since Room cannot give you the list of every change that will happen, without waiting for it to happen.
With this, I'm sure you know why `collect` gives you the records and `toList()` doesn't.

What you probably want here is this.

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM currency")
fun getAllCurrencies(): Flow<List<CurrencyLocalEntity>>
```

With this you can get the first result of the query with `Flow<...>.first()`.

Comment: if we use first() with flow, then Table changes doesn't call the first {} block, again. But if we are using collect {} then any Table changes call the collect {}. Do you any way that we can keep getting table changes in first {} ?

Comment: First gives you the first change. Use collect if you want to get future changes.

Comment: I am not sure about the internal implementation details but do you know what kind of flow (hot or cold) the room exposes? A cold flow with a `while` loop perhaps? Otherwise collector would just listen once, after the `emit` takes place.

Comment: Room gives you a cold flow.

Answer (score 2):

Flow in Room is for observing Changes in table.

Whenever any changes are made to the table, independent of which row is changed, the query will be re-triggered and the Flow will emit again.

However, this behavior of the database also means that if we update an unrelated row, our Flow will emit again, with the same result. Because SQLite database triggers only allow notifications at table level and not at row level, Room can’t know what exactly has changed in the table data

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the same doa object you are using for retrieving the list, is used for updating the database.
other than that converting flow to livedata is done using asLivedata extension function

Answer (score 0):

For me below solution works for updating the view with database table changes.

Solution: Same Dao Object should be used when we insert details into the room database and get information from DB.

If you are using a dagger hilt then

@Singleton annotation will work.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
**getAllCurrencies()** function should be suspend.

Please check the syntax to collect List from Flow: 

suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.toList(
    destination: MutableList<T> = ArrayList()
): List<T> (source)

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/to-list.html
```